# Chunk Account list into List<List<Account>>() based on a condition

Tags: apex, callout, list

I am having trouble with a small piece of code. 
I am calling an API, with List of accounts address. API is working fine, but it gives error when URL endpoint length exceeds 3500.

I have a look on List of accounts from where I am endPoint URL.

```
String destinationStr = '';

    for(Account acc : accls) {

        if(destinationStr.length() < 3500) {
            destinationStr += acc.BillingLatitude + ',' + acc.BillingLongitude + '|';
            acclsToAdd.add(acc);
        }
        else {
            leftOUTAccls.add(acc);
        }
    }
```

I want to create `List<List<Account>>` with this `accls`, so I can iterate over `List<Account>`. I need to add when accounts when `destinationStr` is less than 3550. 
If it exceeds this, then it will be added to next List of accounts in our List of List of accounts

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey Manohar, What is exactly the issue you are trying to get help with? The error from the API or being able to split the account list into two different lists?

Comment: Hi Pablo, thanks your your quick response. API is working fine. 
I just need to split Account list.

Comment: Wont that be better to have `List<String> destinationStrList ;` instead1

Comment: Actually i need to check length of the destinationStr. This string i am passing in distance matrix api End Point. To get travelling distance. There is some limit of end point Url length.

Comment: I don't see what's missing from your code, you are already splitting the list into two other lists based on the destinationStr.length value. Can you clarify please?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in or library functionality that would achieve this: you simply have to write the logic. I'll sketch what I think it could look like in pseudo-code, but you'll have to complete the code yourself based on your specific requirements.

It's not clear to me that you need to be creating batches of Accounts so much as batching Accounts into query-strings that you can send to your web service. However, if you need to batch Accounts, you can incorporate that into the structure below.

```
List<Account> inputAccounts = [SELECT .... FROM Accounts WHERE ...];
List<String> queryStrings = new List<String>();
String currentQuery = ''; // populate the base query for your web service here.

for (Account a : inputAccounts) {
    String thisAccountQuery = acc.BillingLatitude + ',' + acc.BillingLongitude;

    if (currentQuery.length() + thisAccountQuery.length() + 1 <= 3500) {
        currentQuery += '|' + thisAccountQuery; // I'm guessing '|' is a delimiter.
    } else {
        queryStrings.add(currentQuery);
        currentQuery = thisAccountQuery;
    }
}
queryStrings.add(currentQuery);
```

That leaves you with a list of batched strings, each of size less than 3,500, while ensuring that all of your Accounts are covered.

This is *not* copy-pastable code: you'll need to do some work to integrate a structure like this into your actual service calls, and you may need to make significant changes to work with your actual architecture.